# Clone branch so that new one is independent of original branch

Tags: git, github

I have a code which I track with `git  + Github`. Currently I have a master and a test branch:

```
$ git branch
* master
  test-branch
```

What I want to do is to clone the state of `test-branch` into a new `test-branch-2` branch to work with. I know I can do this with:

```
git checkout -b test-branch-2 test-branch
```

If I later on decide I'm done with `test-branch` and delete it (perhaps after merging it into `master`), will this affect my `test-branch-2` at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting your `test-branch` will not affect `test-branch-2`.

If your repository looks like

```
test-branch2            G---H
                       /
test-branch       E---F
                 /
master  A---B---C---D
```

and you merge `test-branch` into `master`, then delete `test-branch` you'll end up with something like this:

```
test-branch2      E---F---G---H
                 /     \
master  A---B---C---D---I
```

Note that `test-branch2` still contains commits `A`, `B`, `C`, `E`, `F`, `G` and `H`, in the same order as before. The new commit `I` is the merge commit from merging `test-branch` into `master`.

If you are interested in the details, I advise you to check out the excellent website [Think like a Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/), particularly the section on [reachability](http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/graph-theory/reachability.html). (If you are new to graph theory, start at the beginning. All you need to know is introduced gradually.)